# How do I use `jpm` with webextension in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, jpm, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm starting a Firefox addon and from what I see:

1. [`jpm` is the tool to manage a Firefox addon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) ;
2. [WebExtensions are a new way to write Firefox extensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/) compatible with the extension API supported by `Google Chrome` and `Opera` ;
3. yet I can't find if `jpm` is usable with [`WebExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions).

#### Question

Is it possible to develop a `WebExtensions` using `jpm`?

Comment: I dont think jpm and webext are compatible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.  They’re two separate ways of developing Firefox add-ons.

Just to add a little more detail, if you’re writing an add-on you want people to use now, you probably want to go with `jpm`.  WebExtensions are still being implemented, and while we at Mozilla would love to hear your input on using the API, they’re not ready for production use at this point (Late September, 2015).  If you do want to write a WebExtension, I’ve written [a tutorial](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/lets_write_a_webextension/) that should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [firefox-addon-skeleton](https://github.com/simomat/firefox-addon-skeleton) for WebExtensions add-on quick-start.