# Unable to run official example

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to run [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension) example. But it won't run.

I've the latest version 45, along with JPM installed. From the command line if I give `"jpm run"` it gives couple of errors like `name` should be in all small letters and no content script specified etc.

How to make it run?

I want some options popup when it's browser icon is clicked. But this part as in package.json is n't working:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/beasts-32.png",
    "default_title": "Beastify",
    "default_popup": "popup/choose_beast.html"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

WebExtensions don't use JPM.

You just pack them into a ZIP file and rename it to XPI and that's it. You can also use the [`web-ext` command-line tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) to do it (`web-ext build`).

For testing your extension, you don't even need to pack it - just open `about:debugging` in your Firefox, click "Load add-on temporarily" and select your extension's main folder.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Packaging_and_installation for details.

Comment: You mean "they do use JPM"? What makes you believe that? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670794/how-do-i-use-jpm-with-webextension-in-firefox/32697550#32697550 and the official bug tracker issue https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/445 where they decided to create a new tool (the `web-ext` I linked) instead of implementing WebExtensions support in JPM.

Comment: @CherryDT Does the old certificate `(--api-key, --api-secret)` used in JPM work for web-ext?